# How can I generate Enunciate documentation in a gradle build

Tags: gradle, enunciate

Enunciate currently does not have a gradle plugin (https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ENUNCIATE-815). Is there any way to trigger a build of the docs from Gradle manually?

Comment: There is now a Gradle plugin for Enunciate 2+. See https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate-gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I needed to supply the various JAX-RS JAR files to enunicate when running it from the command line. This was quite trivial using the configurations.runtime.asPath property in Gradle, which passed through all the RESTEasy artefacts I was already resolving when building the project.

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

task enunciate(type:Exec) {
  if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
      //on windows:
      commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 
      'enunciate-1.29\\bin\\enunciate.bat  -Edocs docs -f enunciate.xml -cp "' + configurations.runtime.asPath + 
      '" src/com/company/rest/RestApi.java'
  } else {
      //on linux
      commandLine './enunciate-1.29/bin/enunciate -Edocs docs -f enunciate.xml -cp "' + configurations.runtime.asPath + 
      " src/com/company/rest/RestApi.java'
  }

  //store the output instead of printing to the console:
  standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

  //extension method stopTomcat.output() can be used to obtain the output:
  ext.output = {
    return standardOutput.toString()
  }
}
```